# Can the column number in a google sheets WHERE clause be a variable?

Tags: variables, google-sheets, where-clause

Can the column number in a where clause be a variable? 
Here's a simple query:

```
=query(MasterData!B2:BR,"Select B where AJ <>''",1)
```

Is it possible to swap out AJ with something like:

```
=match($B$1,MasterData!2:2,0)
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
=query(MasterData!$B$2:$BR,"Select B where 'Col'& match($B$1,MasterData!2:2,0) <>''",1)
```

B1 is a drop down menu and AJ is Col36 The idea is to have the column the where clause evaluates driven by a menu.

Example Data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L01n2U3cJgrt5ILKvv19cwYcBnc-lP7g0dWxrb8knNM/edit?usp=sharing

In this example, I'm trying to fix the formula in the "Query with variable column in WHERE" tab, cell A16

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** *(Following OP's presented sample sheet)*

#### IN SHORT

> Can the column number in a google sheets WHERE clause be a variable?

**Yes it can**

You need to comply with the following

- Use curly quotes `{}` and use `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` etc
- After `Col` use  `"&.......&"` where `......` is **anything that returns the column number**.

As an example

```
=query({C2:H11},"Select Col1, Col5 where Col"&IF(A1=2,2,"xxx")&" <>''",1)
```

---

For this particular question as stated by the OP

You could **use the formula** *(ranges and cells as in your test sheet)*:

```
=query({$C$2:$F},"Select Col1 where Col"&B2&" <>''",1)
```

**OR**

Change your Data validation drop-list in cell `A2` to `2,3,4` and use `A2` in your query instead of `B2`.

**OR**

use any formula within your `where` query clause as long as you get the Column number there.

---

**Original answer**

Assuming the `match` formula itself is correct (giving the correct column number), you would need to correct your query syntax to:

```
=query({MasterData!$B$2:$BR},"Select Col1 where Col"& match($B$1,MasterData!2:2,0)&" <>''",1)
```

You cannot use letters as columns and at the same time use `Col1`, `Col2` etc.
So we use the curly `{}` quotes and everything can be referred as `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col36`

As for when referencing the cell (as `B1` here) the syntax should be
`" & YourCellFormulaHere & "` .

Comment: Thanks, marikamitsos. I’ll try your suggestions. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos and @ChrisRosendin! I tested this answer and it works, it just needs a small `'` after joining the strings. The final result should look like this: 
`=query({MasterData!$B$2:$BR},"Select Col1 where 'Col"& match($B$1,MasterData!2:2,0)&"' <>''",1)`

Comment: Thank you. You are right @Jacques-GuzelHeron. *... and I need some coffee or some sleep. Tough choice :)*

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos  I tried this solution but I get an #N/A. I added example data above. Can you show me my error?

Comment: First of all it is **not your error**. It was my sleep deprivation accomplishments that caused all this. Twice. **1**. I added  an extra `'` in the beginning when manually transferring the formula. **2**. When @Jacques-GuzelHeron tried it, it gave an error which went away by adding a second `'` which now gave `#N/A`. He didn't check why.  So I, instead of checking the formula again, I wrongly trusted his comment and accepted his edit, thus completely ruining the formula. If you now try the (by me) corrected formula in the original answer you will find it working without any flaws. So sorry :(

Comment: So, **as stated in the original answer**: *Assuming the `match` formula itself is correct (giving the correct column number), you would need to **only** correct your query syntax.* Once again, sorry about all this. :(

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos - I REALLY appreciate the help on this. Yes, your solution works as expected an it was the extra '...' that was the cause of the #NA. For the benefit of anyone that might want to do this later, here is a cleaned up example that solves the problem two ways:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L01n2U3cJgrt5ILKvv19cwYcBnc-lP7g0dWxrb8knNM/edit?usp=sharing